# Join two MYSQL WHERE queries together

Tags: mysql

I would like to join the result of 2 queries together so that I end up with 3 columns, first column being the MONTH, second column being WITHDRAWALS and third being DEPOSITS.

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
    SUM(Profit_Loss) AS DEPOSITS
FROM
    `deposits_withdrawals_view`
WHERE
    Summary = 'Cash In'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
    SUM(Profit_Loss) AS WITHDRAWALS
FROM
    `deposits_withdrawals_view`
WHERE
    Summary = 'Cash Out'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")
```

Both work individually but how to I join them together in 1 query?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation for this

```
select
DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
sum(case when Summary='Cash In' then Profit_Loss else 0 end) as DEPOSITS,
sum(case when Summary='Cash Out' then Profit_Loss else 0 end) as WITHDRAWALS
FROM
    `deposits_withdrawals_view`
GROUP BY MONTH
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want join horizontally you can do with this:

```
 select * from (SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
    SUM(Profit_Loss) AS DEPOSITS
FROM
    `deposits_withdrawals_view`
WHERE
    Summary = 'Cash In'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
    SUM(Profit_Loss) AS WITHDRAWALS
FROM
    `deposits_withdrawals_view`
WHERE
    Summary = 'Cash Out'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")) as t2
ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
```

where column1 is the field which used in join (foreign key)

and if you want join vertically

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
    SUM(Profit_Loss) AS DEPOSITS
FROM
    `deposits_withdrawals_view`
WHERE
    Summary = 'Cash In'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")

union all 

SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
    SUM(Profit_Loss) AS WITHDRAWALS
FROM
    `deposits_withdrawals_view`
WHERE
    Summary = 'Cash Out'
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")
```

also you can replace union all with union, where union remove repeated rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y") AS MONTH,
SUM(Profit_Loss) AS DEPOSITS,(SELECT
SUM(Profit_Loss) 
FROM
deposits_withdrawals_view WHERE Summary = 'Cash Out' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")) AS WITHDRAWALS 
FROM deposits_withdrawals_view WHERE Summary = 'Cash In' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Time, "%m-%Y")
```